# Ошибка при запуске GDB Clion на Windows

Tags: c++, windows, clion, gdb

Незаметно для меня прилетело обновление на Clion. Теперь у меня версия 2020.3. После этого обновления происходит ошибка GDB при его запуске

```
Error during pretty printers setup: Error while executing Python code.

Some features and performance optimizations will not be available.
```

После этого я увидел, что значения переменных в принципе перестали выводится.
Искал ответы [тут](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-14177?_ga=2.177985638.259391482.1607379377-1215684682.1604529782) и [тут](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000098784-Python-error-when-debugging), но ничего не помогло. Использую minGW. Переустанавливать пробовал, как Clion, так и minGW. Clion устанавливался через toolbox. Если смотреть ошибку, представленную [здесь](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-14177?_ga=2.177985638.259391482.1607379377-1215684682.1604529782), то вот мои фрагменты

```
WARN - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - >python import sys; sys.dont_write_bytecode = True; sys.path.insert(0, "C:/Users/matve/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/203.5981.166/bin/gdb/renderers"); from default.printers import register_default_printers; register_default_printers(None); from default.libstdcxx_printers import patch_libstdcxx_printers_module; patch_libstdcxx_printers_module();  
WARN - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <^error,msg="Error while executing Python code." 
WARN - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - Error during pretty printers setup: Error while executing Python code.
```

Таких предупреждений у меня много, но они все однотипные

Comment: Написали бы им в поддержку.

Comment: Написал, но ответа не получил. Вот решил еще здесь спросить

Comment: Стоит также сказать, что решения похожих проблем в интернете не являются для меня решением